# what is difference between localhost.log and catalina.log in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

Can you please tell me why there are two log files created on tomcat server?

These two log files are localhost.log and catalina.log.

Thanks!

Comment: If i had to guess, i'd say one's for the server and one's for the domain.  This isn't a programming question, though; it's an admin and/or software one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`catalina.log` is where the Tomcat engine writes log messages pertaining to Tomcat itself.

There's a log for each virtual host. You only have one configured, called `localhost` so that's where the log entries from that host go.

Comment: what is meaning of catalina? It is mentioned at so many places in Tomcat directory structure. Also how can we configure more virtual hosts?

Comment: Catalina is the name of the Tomcat servlet container. I.e. the part that implements the Servlet specification.

Comment: So when we have just one virtualhost (a common use case), we have to check 2 places for relevant messages. Ugh.