# tomcat 8.5.5 identical requests give different RCs 200 or 400

Tags: tomcat

Using tomcat 8.5.5, identical requests result in RC 200 or 400 seemingly randomly, how come?  Here's two  actual log entries:

```
192.168.1.1 - - [22/Feb/2018:05:48:57 -0500] "GET /whiteplainshistory.org//local/images/icons/Heritage_Trail.jpg HTTP/1.1" 400 -

192.168.1.1 - - [22/Feb/2018:05:49:05 -0500] "GET /whiteplainshistory.org//local/images/icons/Heritage_Trail.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3207
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, this could happen if, for example, the server could not accept the request for some reason.

Comment: I think @TimBiegeleisen is on the right track. You may experience 400 HTTP Codes in case the server is still processing a request to the same source. In case of serving an image resource this is quite odd, though. Also check the [Tomcat logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935536/whats-the-difference-between-localhost-log-catalina-log-manager-log-host-man) for errors after you encounter a 400 message.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes it seems that 4xx are "client" errors.  The client made the same request each time.  What error did the client make?

Comment: This seems bad, from catalina...log:

Comment: 22-Feb-2018 17:45:20.128 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-41] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error processing request
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.commit(Http11OutputBuffer.java:332)