# 'Tomcat Localhost Log' vs 'Tomcat Catalina Log' vs 'Server Output' vs 'Event Log'

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea

I debug java project, can not avoid check the print information, in the IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse, there are 4 kind output panel:

[image]

Some times we get an error, like me, first of all, I will go to check the log output information.

But, however, I can not find the related log information firstly. I search the log information one by one, sometimes may be confused by the other log information, such as if the Catalina Log print the useful information, but I was checking the Tomcat Localhost Log, funny is some times I will think the checking log information is related to the issue, so I will be caught in the maze, lost much time.

I don't know if there have others like me, so I want to know:

1. If there has a method if there comes a crash, how can we fast get the most possible log information?
2. Some friend can explain the different between the 4 kind Log? maybe this can help get inspiration.

Comment: Server output contains stdout of the server, localhost/catalina log tabs contain the external log files from Tomcat, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12869506/104891) for details. Event Log is [IDE specific events log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/event-log.html).

Comment: And the answer to your first question would depend on where the error has occurred and on the logging configuration of your web application.